# Unable to change the echo output

Tags: phalcon

I have used PhalconPHP devtools to create a project skeleton and did some testing in the `indexAction(){}` from the indexController.

My index controller:

```
 class IndexController extends ControllerBase

{

    public function indexAction()

    {

        echo "OUUUUUTPUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUT";

    }

}
```

and index.volt looks like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <?php echo $this->view->getContent(); ?>

        {{ content() }}

    </body>

</html>
```

I know this way I am getting double the content. But this is for debugging.
The output I get is:

```html
<h1>Congratulations!</h1>

<p>You are now flying with Phalcon. Great things are about to happen!</p>

<h1>Congratulations!</h1>

<p>You are now flying with Phalcon. Great things are about to happen!</p>
```

I am using Chrome browser for testing, and Ubuntu server 12.04 for PhalconPHP 1.3.0.

Comment: Could you repost the screenshot or just copy paste the output here?

Comment: you can copy the image url and paste it into another tab. The image is resized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phalcon view uses [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), I'm sure that's the reason why you're not seeing the `echo` output, since the view has control over that. You can disable the view to print stuff directly from the controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();
    echo "HELLO";
}
```

To address the actual debugging question, I suggest to stick with [Xdebug](http://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-and-profiling-php-with-xdebug/) – it works perfectly fine with Phalcon and supported by most IDEs, like [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-xdebug.html) or [NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug), and has browser extensions ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en), [Safari](https://github.com/benmatselby/xdebug-toggler), etc.) It takes awhile to get the head around the first time, but the time invested is totally worth it. Highly recommend.

Comment: Thanks! Additional info how I have solved it: adding {{ content() }} to viewsdir/index/index.volt

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is what need:

```
public function testAction(){
    echo 'Hello world';
    $this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_NO_RENDER); //will stop render view
}
```

I use it to output JSON directly from controller. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->view->setContent('OUUUUUTPUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUT');
```

or

```
echo 'OUUUUUTPUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUT';die();
```